# How do I display PHP information using phpinfo()?

Tags: php

I have `phpinfo()` text which I want to post and display on another PHP page.

My code:

###File `index.php`

```
<html>
<form action = "go.php" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "msg"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
<html>
```

###File `go.php :`

```
<?php
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
    echo "Message : ". $message;
?>
```

How can I show PHP info when sending `phpinfo()` text with post data?

Comment: Why don't you place `phpinfo()` in `go.php`?

Comment: Why do you need to send the text for phpinfo() in the POST data?

Comment: I am beginner in php. and I only want to learn.

Answer (score 19):

This question is unclear and probably asked out of some confusion. To display PHP information using phpinfo() you just call this function in a PHP script:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and when you navigate to this page in your browser, it will display the PHP information

In the command line you can get the PHP information using `-i` option:

```
php -i
```

If, for some reason, you want to capture the output of phpinfo() in a variable, you can do this with output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$info = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Why not just use `$info = ob_get_clean();` instead of `$info = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`?

Comment: This is not worked for me. When I use `phpinfo();` method only, it worked for me.

Comment: `$info = ob_end_clean();` returns `true` for me while `$info = ob_get_contents();` works fine.